# How to show a certain tableView row when the view loads

Tags: xcode, uitableview

Instead of showing the tableview starting at row 0, I want to start by showing row 24, which would be way off the initial view. I tried the code below, but it doesn't seem to work.

`[self.tableView setCurrentIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:24 inSection:0]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`
 instead of `setCurrentIndex:`.

`setCurrentIndex` isn't a UITableView method, so having it in your code will prevent the project from building.